# Paso de parametros en DOMPDF. Framework CI3

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Estoy trabajando con la libreria DOMPDF. en la cual recibo algunos datos como estos:

> https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1

Y me gustaria poder ponerlos en el PDF. Mi código es el siguiente:

```
public function index()
    {
        $data = file_get_contents('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1');
        $item = json_decode($data, true);
        // instantiate and use the dompdf class
        $dompdf = new Dompdf();

        $html = $this->load->view('pdf',$item,true);

        $dompdf->loadHtml($html);

        // (Optional) Setup the paper size and orientation
        $dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');

        // Render the HTML as PDF
        $dompdf->render();

        // Get the generated PDF file contents
        $pdf = $dompdf->output();

        // Output the generated PDF to Browser
        $dompdf->stream();
    }
```

y mi vista es la siguiente:

```
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        
    <h1>probando probando <?php echo $item['name'] ?> </h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Me pone el error que la variable $item no existe. Que puede ser? O como podria hacer algun paso de parametros. Muchas gracias!

Comment: y como pasas la variable item del php al html??

Answer (score 1):

En CodeIgniter cuando cargas una view y pasas el segundo parámetro, las keys del arreglo se usan como variables dentro de la view, por ejemplo (en CodeIgniter 3):

#### Controlador:

```php
<?php
class Foo extends CI_Controller {
    public function index() {
        $data = array(
            'name' => 'Leanne Graham'
        );
        $this->load->view('foo-view', $data);
    }

}
```

#### En la vista foo-view:

```php
<html>
    <body>
        <p> <?php echo $name; ?> </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Docs: https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/views.html

Comment: creonque me perdi de algo el OP dijo que co  codeigniter?